# Cannot implicity convert type void to System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool>

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, asynchronous, task

I have a WCF Service that contains the following method. All the methods in the service are asynchrounous and compile just fine.

```
public async Task<Boolean> ValidateRegistrationAsync(String strUserName)
{
    try
    {
        using (YeagerTechEntities DbContext = new YeagerTechEntities())
        {
            DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();

            var reg = await DbContext.aspnet_Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.UserName == strUserName);

            if (reg != null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

My client application was set to access the WCF service with the check box for the "Allow generation of asynchronous operations" and it generated the proxy just fine.

I am receiving the above subject error when trying to call this WCF service method from my client with the following code. Mind you, I know what the error message means, but this is my first time trying to call an asynchronous task in a WCF service from a client.

```
Task<Boolean> blnMbrShip = db.ValidateRegistrationAsync(FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cn.Value).Name);
```

**What do I need to do to properly call the method so the design time compile error disappears?**

Comment: You have a rep of 572. You have zero excuse for posting such badly formatted code. Fix it please.

Comment: Well have you looked at the signature for the generated proxy code?

Comment: Jon, the generated proxy code is as follows: public void ValidateRegistrationAsync(string strUserName) {
            this.ValidateRegistrationAsync(strUserName, null); I'm expecting it to return a Boolean. I don't know whether I have the WCF service method or the client code incorrect.
        }

Comment: David, what is wrong with the formatted code? The WCF method is exactly how it is in visual studio with the CTRL-K format and the client code is just one line also formatted with the CTRL-K. So I don't know what your problem is...

Answer (score 1):

The WCF proxy is old; try to re-create the proxy with a newer (VS2012/VS2013) proxy generator.

Specifically, it is generating [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) endpoints, and you need [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) endpoints.

If this is for a Silverlight client, then the auto-generated proxy will refuse to create TAP methods. In that case, you'd need to write your own wrappers (which are [pretty easy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ApmToTap), just rather tedious).

Comment: Stephen, I am using VS 2013. This is NOT for a Silverlight project. I just glanced over the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern link, but am unsure what I still need to do. Do I need to change a setting when generating the Service Reference? If so, could you please give a little more detail. Thanks you so much...

Comment: @sagesky36: You should be able to just create the proxy. Asynchronous should be selected by default, and it should generate TAP endpoints. Could you create a minimal repro project and upload it (e.g., http://ge.tt/ ?)

Comment: Stephen, thanks so much for helping me out. I've been extremely busy at work and haven't had a chance yet to get back to this project. I will do as you said and upload it as soon as I get a chance. Once again, thanks so much.

Comment: Stephen, thanks again, but I was able to get the proxy created just by re-booting my machine, launching VS 2013, cleaning the solution, and then adding the service.